# Remove username suggest function in Skype 4.2, Windows Vista?

Tags: skype

My dad currently uses one of my old machines for chat and email and such and most recently, Skype.  However, there are a bunch of old suggested screennames belonging to other people who may have used my machine from time to time and I don't want my father to see these for a number of reasons.

Is there anyway to make Skype 'forget' who has logged in before?  I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the entire Skype folder? Since it must be stored somewhere. If not, then the data must be in the cloud and you should give him a different account name

Comment: Well the data is not in the cloud because it prompts him with usernames at the login screen.  However, I would have assumed that a hardcore Windows uninstall hammer would have done the trick :/

Comment: I assume it leaves traces of Skype in your application folder (where this is depends on your Windows version), these aren't always deleted when you uninstall something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a guide by Skype](https://support.skype.com/faq/FA10634/How-can-I-completely-uninstall-and-then-reinstall-Skype?frompage=search&q=uninstall) itself on **completely** uninstalling Skype

> Save your personal information (if required). Your contacts, purchases and account information are stored on our servers, but other personal files such as chat messages, voicemail and snapshots taken during video calls, are only saved on your computer. To keep this personal information, you need to make a copy of it.
>
> - Vista and 7: Click Start, type run and press Enter.
> - XP: Click Start and then Run...
> - Type %appdata%\skype and click OK.
> - Copy the Pictures folder and the folder with your Skype name to another location, such as your desktop.
>
> Uninstall Skype.
>
> - Vista and 7: Click Start, type run and press Enter.
> - XP: Click Start and then Run...
> - Type appwiz.cpl and click OK.
> - Select Skype from the list, right-click and select Remove or Uninstall.
>
> **Delete the Skype application folder.**
>
> - Vista and 7: Click Start, type run and press Enter.
> - XP: Click Start and then Run...
> - Type %appdata% and click OK.
> - Delete the Skype folder.
> - Ensure that the Skype program folder has been deleted.
> - Go to C:\Program Files
> - Delete the Skype folder and the SkypePM folder (if present).
>
> Delete any Skype entries from the Registry.
>
> - Vista and 7: Click Start, type run and press Enter.
> - XP: Click Start and then Run...
> - Type regedit and click OK.
> - In the Edit menu, click Find.
> - Search for the keyword Skype.
> - Use right-click to delete all the search results (there can be up to 50).

Comment: Or use something like Revo Uninstaller :-)

Comment: Is that as thoroughly @Nifle?

Comment: Well I can't promise as every situation is a bit different. But when I changed my skype username I had similar problems (a simple reinstall did not fix it) I told Revo to do it's deepest scan and it fixed the problem.

Comment: Downvote because: uninstalling Skype does not clear username information, tried with version 8 on windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

The usernames for Skype (and also for other programs) are stored in Windows Control panel / user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

As noticed by @David Balažic, above solutions don't work on more recent versions of Skype because there is simply no Skype folder in %appdata%.

Here is a workaround I found:

1. quit Skype
2. delete the folder "%appdata%\Microsoft\Teams\Session Storage"
3. log into the account you want to remove from the login screen
4. log out: Skype should ask if you want to save login information. Say no
5. now the login screen should be free of this account!

Beware that it might alter stuff in Microsoft Teams, I have not tested this since I do not use Teams.

Edit: just noticed @David Balažic's answer, but I think mine is still useful since in my case the credentials were stored by Skype but not by Windows.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to just remove the usernames and leave Skype on your system, just [delete the profile](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=57236) from your computer and it should no longer suggest the username at login.

You should find a path similar to the following:

> `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Skype`

That path should show folders such as Content, My Skpe Received Files and Wallpapers among others.

Just look for the username folder in that and delete it. Restart Skype and you should now no longer have the recently deleted username suggested.

Comment: another step-by-step guide here: http://superuser.com/questions/269769/how-to-clear-history-in-skype/269999#269999

Comment: This does not work with recent versions.