# Clear history of usernames in Skype

Tags: skype, history, user-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove username suggest function in Skype 4.2, Windows Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/175436/remove-username-suggest-function-in-Skype-4-2-Windows-Vista)

I'm looking for a way to clear the login name history on my Skype (Windows 7).

I don't know where it is hidden. Even tried un-installing all Skype and re-installing again but still it is showing the previous history of names logged in.

How do I delete these from the suggested drop-down login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step-by-step:

- Click the Start menu
- Click `Run` (or just press <kbd>WinKey</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)
- Type `%AppData%/Skype`
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard
- In the folder that appears, look for a folder named with the user you want to get rid of
- Delete that folder.

That should clear the username from your login field.

Comment: This does not work for version 8 of Skype for Windows (Desktop).

Comment: Thanks @DavidBalažic. At this point, this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as :

`Tools > Options > Privacy Settings > Clear History`

Comment: im using FireFox and tried Tools/Options/Privacy > Clear History ... But still in skype i can see my previous login name..  Is there any other suggestion?

Comment: This is the right question: using windows7 Does anyone know how to clear the skype name in drop down list during login?

Comment: Apparently it does not clear the login names (as mentioned by anonymous user).